# Need to access file content from class file of C# web Application

Tags: c#, web, hosting, httpcontext

I am trying read an email template from the background job which has been written in class file. I tried to use `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/path")` but it did not work as `HttpContext` is not valid.

Also I tried to use `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/path")` and I am getting path but it's throwing error as could not find file.
Our application is hosted in shared hosting.

Any idea how can I read file content from class file in C# Web Application.

Comment: try something like this 
`Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, someFile);`

Answer (score 0):

Class files are compiled and not included as content. That is why you are not able to access template. If you want to access the template as a property then create a class in the file and have a property/field exposing the template.

```cs
public static class Templates {
    public static string Email_Template = "{email template}";
}
```

I had a similar situation where i needed access to a template for email and also markdown documentation for an api.

Here is how I solved my problem.

- Created **App_Data** folder in Web Application project.
- Created template file in the folder created previously and populate it with email template. Mine was *EmailTemplate.txt* / *Documentation.md*

> *EmailTemplate.txt*
>
> {this is my email template}

- Assuming you are using Visual Studio, in the properties tab for the files,set the **Build Action** to **Content**
- To access content of files:

```cs
var path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/EmailTemplate.txt");
var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
//Do whatever formatting I needed to do with the template
```

If HttpContext is not working then try it this

```cs
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/EmailTemplate.txt");
```

But remember that you need to make the template file accessible as content in order for it to be accessible.

Comment: I have similar set-up in my project, but instead of App_Data folder, I created Content folder and kept the templates under Content folder. My Build Action is also set to content. Will it matter if I do not use App_Data?

Comment: Yes. The intended use of `App_Data` folder is to store application data for the **web process** to access. Thus it can be accessed from application code.